# SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE error only on PC Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox, iis, browser, certificate

This site (https://ssptrades.com) is currently giving me SSL problems... but only PC Firefox.

I can tell the certificate is TSL 1.2 by looking at it in another browser...would that be a problem? If it is how can I generate a certifcate or certificate request for TLS 1.3 using IIS?

This is the error on pc firefox 81.0.2 (64 bit)

An error occurred during a connection to ssptrades.com. Peer’s Certificate has been revoked.

Error code: SEC_ERROR_REVOKED_CERTIFICATE

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Comment: If you end up here on late January 2022 and are using LetsEncrypt, they just revoked a lot of certificates: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/lets-encrypt-is-revoking-lots-of-ssl-certificates-in-two-days/. You have to renew them, with certbot for example. If using Traefik, you might have to delete the certificate files (acme.json) and restart Traefik for it to renew the certificates with LE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell why neither Chrome nor Edge check the revocation status, but Firefox is right. The certificate was revoked on Nov. 5 since GoDaddy believes that ssptrades.com has stopped operations.

## How to check revocation manually

1. Save the certificate of ssptrades.com to the file `site.cer`, and the issuer's certificate to the file [gd1.cer](https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/27ac9369faf25207bb2627cefaccbe4ef9c319b8.pem)
2. Obtain the URL to OCSP service:

```
openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in site.cer
```

Output: `http://ocsp.godaddy.com/`

3. Check OCSP status:

```
openssl ocsp -issuer gd1.cer -cert site.cer -text -url http://ocsp.godaddy.com/
```

(shortened) output:

```
OCSP Response Data:
    OCSP Response Status: successful (0x0)
    Response Type: Basic OCSP Response
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Responder Id: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = GoDaddy Inc., CN = Go Daddy Validation Authority - G2
    Produced At: Nov  6 20:11:53 2020 GMT
    Responses:
    Certificate ID:
      Hash Algorithm: sha1
      Issuer Name Hash: B6080D5F6C6B76EB13E438A5F8660BA85233344E
      Issuer Key Hash: 40C2BD278ECC348330A233D7FB6CB3F0B42C80CE
      Serial Number: 54FC3E8F69D995CF
    Cert Status: revoked
    Revocation Time: Nov  5 20:08:54 2020 GMT
    Revocation Reason: cessationOfOperation (0x5)
```

The last threee lines tell us: the certificate was revoked on Nov 5, the reason is "cessation of operations" (code 0x5)

Comment: GoDaddy claimed that everything was fine... but after 6 phone calls and doing the same thing 6 times it finally worked... my suspicion is they fixed something on their end.

Comment: @BrianRice yep! Not revoked any more. Congrats on fixing this!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox is right in that the certificate is revoked. This can be verified with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=ssptrades.com&latest):

[image]
...
[image]

Why you see this only in Firefox? Because likely the other browsers don't properly check for revocation - see [How well do current browsers handle certificate revocation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219443/how-well-do-current-browsers-handle-certificate-revocation) or [How Do Browsers Handle Revoked SSL/TLS Certificates?](https://www.ssl.com/article/how-do-browsers-handle-revoked-ssl-tls-certificates/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are aware of this and you want to bypass this error in Firefox,
Go to Settings, Privacy and Security, under Security, find Certificates. Turn Query OCSP off.